# Window & door lock not working on Golf Extra

Tags: electrical, vw, troubleshooting, golf, switches

The window & door locks are not working on my Golf Extra Drivers side rear door. I suspect a broken common, possibly earth ground.

Any pointers regarding troubleshooting my issue would be appreciated before I go ripping the internal fascia off!

What can I do to diagnose and remediate this problem?

Comment: Since it's only one door, i'd say you're correct in assuming it's an electrical gremlin within that door rather than with a control module or fuse.

Comment: What year model?

Comment: Thanks Lucifer. I just hope it's not broken before it gets into the door!

Comment: Moab it's a 10 plate.